# How is Credit Card Interest charged?

Tags: united-states, credit-card

It is my understanding that if have an outstanding balance on most credit card and you use it make a purchase then the interest will start to accrue from the date of purchase. However, I thought that there was a law passed a while back saying the credit card companies could not do that? Did the law change? or did the law never exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It is my understanding that if have an outstanding balance on most credit card and you use it make a purchase then the interest will start to accrue from the date of purchase.

Your understanding is correct. The interest-free grace period on new credit card purchases is generally only good if you have paid your last statement balance in full by the statement due date. If you carry any balance over, any new purchases for the next month will accrue interest starting from the date of purchase.

> However, I thought that there was a law passed a while back saying the credit card companies could not do that? Did the law change? or did the law never exist?

As far as I know, there is no law to prohibit this practice. The most recent credit card reform law, the [Credit CARD Act of 2009](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_CARD_Act_of_2009), made a number of changes to how credit cards can operate, but it did not prohibit the suspending of the grace period when carrying a balance.